# Disable select(dropdown) on checkbox click (React JS and Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React JS application and i am using material UI with it.
I have grid like below
[image]

My requirement is when i click on a checkbox only that particular row's select should get enabled. I have tried with disabled attribute and document.getElementById but no luck.

HTML code for Select

```
<FormControl name="selectDdl" id={`selectHr${index}`}  variant="outlined" className='selectLayout' >
            <Select id={`selectHrs${index}`}  disabled={isSelectDisabled} name = {`selectHrs${index}`} >
            {optionItemsHours}
            </Select>
```

Code to enable the dropdown

```
const chkDays = (event) => {
  
 var selectHr = document.getElementById("selectHr0");
 selectHr.disabled = false;
 document.getElementById("selectHr0").children[0].classList.remove("Mui-disabled");
// setisSelectDisabled(false); -- this disable all dropdown of page
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using react its not good to modify dom directly. I have created small example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-microservice-l5m6k

You can modify this as per your need.

Comment: Thank you @vishal. this works finr for a single dropdown. I am facing issues with multiple dropdown and same flag is used to set to disable/enable them

Comment: I have modified the above example for multiple checkbox. You can change state as per your need and modify the html. https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-microservice-l5m6k